# Related list with custom button is not getting updated when a new record is saved

Tags: custom-button, related-list, urlhacking, list-button

I'm using a custom list button to create records. It's working, but when a new record is created and saved, I need to refresh the full page to see the new record at the related list. I wish I didn't have to refresh the page to see the new record.

Here's the URL Hack I'm using:

> /lightning/o/Related_Contacts__c/new?defaultFieldValues=Contact__c={!Form__c.ContactId__c},Contact1__c={!Form__c.ContactId__c},Form__c={!Form__c.Id}&navigationLocation=RELATED_LIST&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FForm__c%2F{!Form__c.Id}%2Fview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on similar solution. It's working as expected for me. Below is my URL hack

> /lightning/o/Contact/new?defaultFieldValues=AccountId={!Account.Id},LastName=Vamsy&navigationLocation=RELATED_LIST&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FAccount%2F{!Account.Id}%2Fview

Comment: The problem persists for me, but I realized that the problem only happens if the related list is at the end of a page long enough that I need to scroll to see it. When the related list is in the visible part of the page, where I don't need to scroll to reach it, the update happens normally, as expected.